# Running different python scripts depending on users' selection (customization mode/ play mode)

Tags: python, tkinter, mode

I want to design 2 modes for an application.

- Customization mode: Users can make changes to interface objects (e.g. moving button to diiferent position).
- Play Mode: User can only use buttons to perform certain task they are designed for but can't edit them.

User should be able to switch between those modes. Once users exit from the customization mode, they should see the changes made in that mode.

Thank you.

I have not started working on it yet. I am still thinking about the way to do it. Is there any example you came accross. I tried, couldn't find anything so far. Thank you

Comment: SO is not a place for asking code from scratch.  You need to try doing it yourself and raise question on problem you come across.

Comment: I understand this and will take better care next time. That's something unpublished. So, not sure if it's ok to share the whole idea and code before publishing it. Thank you

Comment: You don't need to show the code that cannot be published. Just create a simple example, for example just a button in a window.  The try to think how to switch mode and move the button in *customize* mode.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a basic example to implement these two modes in your application, you can expand on this and add more functionality as needed.

```
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mode = 'play'
        # initialize buttons and interface objects

    def switch_mode(self):
        if self.mode == 'play':
            self.mode = 'customization'
            # enable customization mode
        else:
            self.mode = 'play'
            # enable play mode

    def handle_button_click(self, button):
        if self.mode == 'play':
            # perform action associated with button
        else:
            # enable button dragging and dropping
```

Use a flag to indicate the current mode (customization or play) and control the behavior of the buttons. In customization mode, users can drag and drop buttons to different positions and make changes to the interface objects and save the changes, while in play mode, users can disable the customization features and load the saved changes and update the interface accordingly.

An example of implementing the idea using `tkinter':

```
import tkinter as tk

def customization_mode():
    for widget in widgets:
        widget.config(state='normal')

def play_mode():
    for widget in widgets:
        widget.config(state='disabled')

root = tk.Tk()

widgets = []

# add widgets to the GUI

mode_button = tk.Button(root, text="Toggle mode", command=lambda: toggle_mode())
mode_button.pack()

def toggle_mode():
    if mode_button['text'] == "Customization mode":
        customization_mode()
        mode_button.config(text="Play mode")
    else:
        play_mode()
        mode_button.config(text="Customization mode")

root.mainloop()
```